# Access Select specific tables to update, change and modify

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, edit

I create a DB where each table is a different project. 
However, i am not sure how i would go about creating a form in which a user can choose a specific table (project) from a drop down menu and than be able to update/edit/modify the contents in the table.

Each table is standardized to contain exact column headers.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: Your table design is flawed. All project data should be in **one** table, with a foreign key to a "Projects" table. Of course you can build workarounds with modifying `Form.RecordSource`, but you really should rethink your approach.

Comment: Andre, 
I tried to have each project be a different table because the initial project is uploaded to access from a different excel sheet

Comment: That's not a problem, you can import them with an INSERT query into one (existing) table, just add the foreign key.

Comment: Andre, 
Thanks that sounds like a much better plan.